# Correct usage in a sentence: kept quiet vs remained quiet

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence:

> I asked her what her problem was, but she -------------------- quiet

The answer "remained quiet" was marked wrong and the correct answer was given as "kept quiet".

No reason was provided in the answer key.

Can you let me know why the use of remained quiet is wrong and why kept quiet should be used?

Searching on the net indicates the use of "remained silent" in sentences but could not find any references that indicate the use of "remained quiet" in a sentence is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm both *remained quiet* and *kept quiet* are correct and mean the same thing in this sentence, I don't know why it was incorrect.

Comment: The only conceivable interpretation of *kept* being fine but *remained* not being fine, would be if *quiet* (or perhaps I should say *Quiet*) were a proper noun rather than an adjective. If I own a box named "Quiet," I can *keep* it in a drawer, but I can't *remain* it in a drawer. That aside, and I think it's too contrived for the question, there is no difference in meaning.